# Software to handle large Excel .xls files

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

Some users receive XLS files from other offices for analysis, but these files are extremely large and the performance of Excel is low.  I know the best solution could be transfer this information to a DB manager but this is not practical right now.   Is there software designed to handle a large number of records in Excel? I am using Windows 7 with a PC (AMD APU A6 7400 K a 3.50 GHz
Ram 4GB DDR3)

Comment: Its often helpful to set Calculation to Manual, working on file locally - not on a network drive, and sometimes setting up conditional formats (fill colours) will help analysis and can be used with filters.

Comment: Only XLS or mainly XLSX? The old XLS format is quite proprietary.

Answer (score 1):

[Python](http://python.org) + [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) can import from Excel and can handle manipulation of very large data sets.

Both are free and cross platform.